# Azure DevOps Rest API - Authentication

Tags: azure-devops, azure-active-directory

I need to build a Powershell Module which needs to distributed. I cannot use personal token for authentication. I have to use an interactive authentication to call azure devOps REST API [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)

What would be the target APIResourceId in Oauth2 authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resourceId is always `499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798`.

See e.g. https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-auth-samples/blob/master/ManagedClientConsoleAppSample/Program.cs